# Why are female offenders given lesser sentences for the same crime as men?

Tags: united-states, crime, discrimination, gender

I'm particularly talking about student-teacher relationships. Females are usually given less punishment for the same or a similar crime.  A couple of years ago I found my former high school teacher had an inappropriate relationship with two of his students (in Texas). Both were of 18 years of age at the time of the incident. [more detail about it](http://www.arlingtonvoice.com/story/feb/28/2012/arlington-teacher-arrested-inappropriate-relationship-students). He was sentenced two years ago and was given the maximum sentence of 20 years.

A female teacher in Texas who also had an inappropriate relationship with a student was given five years and the victims were also 18 at the time. She had relationships with five of her students. [here's the story](http://www.nbcdfw.com/news/local/Kennedale-Teacher-Guilty-on-All-Counts-166547756.html).

In another case, Stacy Schuler, a 33 year old high school teacher, was convicted of 16 felony counts of sexual battery and three misdemeanor counts of providing alcohol to minors. She was sentenced to four years in prison and she invited the high school football team to her house where they engaged in sexual acts. Some were under the age of 18 [here's the story](http://www.people.com/people/article/0,,20540332,00.html).

Why is there such a big gap between these punishments for the same crimes??

Comment: I'm not sure this is a politics question.  I'm also not sure three examples is sufficient to prove a case, or whether it's just sampling bias.  Definitely an interesting question, though, and a good topic for a research paper.

Comment: Yes, we need a whole lot more data here to establish the premise. These are just 3 anecdotes.

Comment: There's plenty of statistics on issues of other charges unrelated to student teacher relationships. There's much more than the three I posted. It would be too long for me to post them all

Comment: This appears to be a question for https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't post them all.  Find a study that talks about them as a group and post that.  The plural of anecdote is not data.  You want a data source that tries to be comprehensive.

Comment: Law \ attorney \ judges and politics go hand and hand. I get the two confused myself but sounds like a legal question for the law SE site.

Comment: We have a question on meta about the topic when a question is law and when it's politics: http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71/where-how-do-we-draw-the-line-between-legal-and-political-questions

Comment: @Bobson - the sentencing disparity is a proven fact using existing research. A basic [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=gender+sentencing+disparity+underage+sex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) shows up 2 state-specific studies (NJ and AZ) and a general reference **just on the first page**

Comment: @Bobson - For a less statistical but more law-study treatment: "Journal of Criminal Law and Criminology, Volume 85, Issue 1: Summer; Article 4 ; Summer 1994; The Role of Gender in a Structured Sentencing System: Equal Treatment, Policy Choices, and the Sentencing of Female Offenders under the United States Sentencing Guidelines"

Comment: @user4012 - I never said it wasn't. I said three examples didn't prove anything. Since the studies *have* been done, the question should cite/link those instead of individual cases.

Comment: @Killer066 I suspect the broader class of 'sexual offenses' covers what you're interested in and may have more formal studies done on it.

Comment: Q: *Why is there such a big gap between these punishments for the same crimes??*  This kind of relates to Q2: *Why is there such a big gap between the pay men and women get for the same work??*

Comment: @Bobson - the question can be *improved* by citing... but on Politics there's no "should" requirement for citing the assumptions. (not saying that's good or bad, but it's the status quo)

Comment: @user4012 - I'd frame it as: "You always *should* cite your evidence, but on Politics it's not a *must*."  It's the difference between being able to answer "I counter your anecdotes with other anecdotes" and/or "Your anecdotes don't prove anything" and having to answer "Here's a researched reason"

Comment: I don't have evidence, but my gut says it is likely based on the misconception that women are less able to coerce or harm their victims. That is especially stupid in a context where coercive powers other than physical violence  exist. That is obviously true of teachers or employers.

Comment: @Bobson in Russia and many other countries it is in the law: punishment for women is less than for men.

Comment: @Anixx - That sounds like it should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The untested premise here is that males receive harsher sentences for these kinds of crimes than females.

To address your question and provide you with references you can read, I won't cite anything behind a paywall, which is tough. Luckily, someone posted their [M.A. thesis](https://repository.asu.edu/attachments/97779/content/tmp/package-bzXXXU/Simmon_asu_0010N_12405.pdf) on exactly this subject online for free. It was completed in 2012 under the faculty at Arizona State University.

I'll summarize some key points below. You can refer to the original document for their references. If you have access to an academic database, you can read the referenced articles there.

### In General, Females Receive More Lenient Sentences than Males

The literature review discusses gender differences in sentencing, and concludes that males receive harsher sentences than females. It also states that this tends to happen because judges deviate from sentencing guidelines more often when sentencing females.

### Sentencing Regarding Improper Relationships with Students

This research examined sentencing for cases within a single area in Arizona over a 10 year period. They note that 1 case was rejected because they could not procure records, leaving them with 13 cases of teachers having inappropriate relationships with students.

These 13 cases involved 16 teachers - 11 male and 5 female. Two of the victims were male, the remaining victims were all female. The methods section describes more about the cases and their similarities/differences.

The project finds that the female teachers were generally given the minimum sentence, while male teachers were generally given something closer to the presumptive sentence (which is what you get unless some other factor increases/decreases it). Since the presumptive sentence is the default, it seems that judges deviated from the presumptive sentence for female perpetrators.

### Explanations

Their research does not attempt to identify a singular reason for this, but identifies three possibilities for a gender gap in sentencing in the literature review section. These are theoretical grounds for *any* gender gap in sentencing, not just this type of crime:

1. Judicial paternalism - Judges are usually male, and may treat sentencing perpetrators like disciplining children. Therefore, they may give females lighter sentences than males.
2. Chivalry - Judges feel they are protecting females from punishment which is too intense to be suitable for them. One spin on this is that females may more often be seen as responsible for childcare, and so the family is being protected when the woman is protected.
3. Focal theory - Females are seen as less blameworthy than males, females are viewed as being intrinsically less of a risk to society than males, and it may be perceived that females need to be shielded from harsh punishments.

### Caveats

This research shows that in a limited area, females do receive harsher punishments than males for having improper relationships with students. It outlines some theoretical reasons why. It was conducted under the guidance of experienced faculty who know how to do good research.

However - it can not be generalized to other areas and it doesn't fully explore *why* this happens. Despite these limitations, it decently answers part of your question and hopefully guides you to a better explanation.

Comment: None of those reasons really feel right to me - they all seem to be variants on "judges think women are weak", which might explain *some* cases, but ring false for a large sample.  I prefer the reason put forth in a (opinion-based and now deleted) answer which posited that there is an assumption that  more coercion is involved in male-teacher-female-student cases than the reverse.  That said, good job finding that thesis, and this is exactly the *type* of answer this question needs.

Comment: I'm not an expect on this subject. But if you prefer an opinion-based reason to scientific research, there isn't much I can do to help alleviate your concerns.

Comment: I approve of the *research* in the paper and the conclusions it reaches ("differences exist"). I just don't think the *theoretical* explanations presented in the review are sufficient to explain it.  After skimming the paper, I think my issue is really that you mischaracterize that section. Those theories are presented as a sample of reasons for sentencing discrepancies **in general**, which may or may not be relevant here. The author doesn't posit any reason himself or claim they are applicable (or not) here.

Comment: I'll edit to make that more clear, although that is definitely what I intended.

Comment: I edited to try and address my concern about that section.  Please feel free to roll it back if you think it changes your intent too much.

Comment: You say "This research shows that in a limited area, females do receive harsher punishments than males". What limited area was that? Or is that sentence just wrong?

Comment: Within the specific counties in Arizona within the time period covered by the researcher.

Comment: There is an apparent  non sequiturn,  the thesis shows  that males tend to receive harsher sentences, not females.  Or I have misunderstood..?

Comment: You seem to understand correctly. That is also what the question asked about.

Comment: In Russia the most judges are women, but still men receive much harsher sentences.

Comment: @Anixx While interesting, I am not sure what it has to do with a question and answer about politics in the US.

Comment: @indigochild I do not see in the question that it asks about the United States.

Comment: @Anixx It's in the tags. The question would be improved by mentioning it in the text, but for now it isn't.

Comment: @indigochild the tag was added by another user, not the OP.